# Get twilio callback on call screen success and also on failure

Tags: twilio

I have some working code for call screening with NodeJS, which I modified from the official twilio example.

- https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/callscreening
- https://github.com/coolaj86/bizilio/blob/master/routes/twilio/voice/index.js#L246

Snippit:

```
response += ""
  + '<Response><Gather action="/twilio/voice/connect' + search + '" finishOnKey="any digit" numDigits="1">'
  + '<Say>Press any key to accept this call</Say>'
  + '</Gather>'
  // TODO instead of hanging up, redirect to voicemail?
  // otherwise it's left to the fallback url to pickup the voicemail and that takes a while
  + '<Hangup/>'
  + '</Response>'
  ;
```

If the screening completes successfully, I get a callback to `/twilio/voice/connect?foo=bar`.

**If the screening is unsuccessful** I also want a callback to `/twilio/voice/miss?foo=bar`.

Is the most appropriate way to do this to do a `<Redirect>` instead of `<Hangup/>` and then do the `<Hangup/>` in the redirect? Or should I had a `statusCallback` somewhere in the original dial and reference the call id?

In thinking about the possibilities to write out the question here, I've probably already discovered a working solution (and I'll go try it), but I'd still like to hear a best practice approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suggest, you should replace the `<Hangup>` with a `<Redirect>/twilio/voice/miss?foo=bar</Redirect>`. After the timeout expires (by default 5 seconds, but configurable via the `timeout` attribute of the Gather verb), if no input has been received it will go to the next instruction.

From the [Twilio Docs for `<Gather>`](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather):

> If no input is received before timeout,  falls through to the next verb in the TwiML document.

In the URL that you redirect to you can record that no input was gathered and return any TwiML you like to continue processing the call or return an empty `<Response></Response>` (or Hangup) to end the call.

StatusCallback is only used at the completion of the call and cannot execute further TwiML instructions.